# How do I reset a django app and start clean both with south migrations and in the database?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I need a way to just hit "reset" on an app both for south migrations and in the database.

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not terribly difficult to do it manually:

```
$ python manage.py sqlclear myapp
```

will give you SQL commands to wipe your current app tables -- you might want to list all tables beginning with app name to see old ones if you have them.

South stores its migration history in another database table, so you should be able to kill them with this SQL command:

```
DELETE FROM south_migrationhistory WHERE app_name = 'myapp';
```